# pgfplots wrong colors in surface plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, 3d

I am trying to plot 3d data as a surface plot. However the color of the surface is wrong. I tried different shaders but none of the shaders seem to work. I think the color should be the same for the same values of Z.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=2.018in,
height=1.698in,
at={(0.339in,0.229in)},
scale only axis,
point meta min=0,
point meta max=1.8,
xmin=0,
xmax=0.2,
tick align=outside,
xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
xlabel={$X$},
ymin=0,
ymax=1.6,
ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
ylabel={$Y$},
zmin=0,
zmax=2,
zlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
zlabel={$Z$},
view={-45}{45},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
axis z line*=left,
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
zmajorgrids
]

\addplot3[%
surf,
shader=interp, draw=black, z buffer=sort, colormap/jet, mesh/rows=10]
table[row sep=crcr, point meta=\thisrow{c}] {%
%
x   y   z   c\\
0.02    0.1 0.000836933014342034    0.000836933014342034\\
0.02    0.2 0.00334773205736814 0.00334773205736814\\
0.02    0.3 0.00753239711883609 0.00753239711883609\\
0.02    0.4 0.013390928208828   0.013390928208828\\
0.02    0.5 0.0209233253274806  0.0209233253274806\\
0.02    0.6 0.030129588474806   0.030129588474806\\
0.02    0.7 0.0410097176508092  0.0410097176508092\\
0.02    0.8 0.0535637128554926  0.0535637128554926\\
0.02    0.9 0.0677915740888575  0.0677915740888575\\
0.02    1   0.0836933013509049  0.0836933013509049\\
0.02    1.1 0.101268894633832   0.101268894633832\\
0.02    1.2 0.1205183539637 0.1205183539637\\
0.02    1.3 0.141441679271941   0.141441679271941\\
0.02    1.4 0.16403887060397    0.16403887060397\\
0.02    1.5 0.188309927963666   0.188309927963666\\
0.02    1.6 0.214254851351224   0.214254851351224\\
0.04    0.1 0.00156389526495684 0.00156389526495684\\
0.04    0.2 0.00625558105982738 0.00625558105982738\\
0.04    0.3 0.0140750573743694  0.0140750573743694\\
0.04    0.4 0.025022324218665   0.025022324218665\\
0.04    0.5 0.0390973815928508  0.0390973815928508\\
0.04    0.6 0.0563002294969392  0.0563002294969392\\
0.04    0.7 0.0766308679309348  0.0766308679309348\\
0.04    0.8 0.10008929689484    0.10008929689484\\
0.04    0.9 0.126675516388657   0.126675516388657\\
0.04    1   0.156389526412386   0.156389526412386\\
0.04    1.1 0.189231326958224   0.189231326958224\\
0.04    1.2 0.225200918052232   0.225200918052232\\
0.04    1.3 0.264298299625844   0.264298299625844\\
0.04    1.4 0.306523471724472   0.306523471724472\\
0.04    1.5 0.351876434351998   0.351876434351998\\
0.04    1.6 0.400357187508615   0.400357187508615\\
0.06    0.1 0.00229665158772114 0.00229665158772114\\
0.06    0.2 0.00918660635088458 0.00918660635088458\\
0.06    0.3 0.0206698642792481  0.0206698642792481\\
0.06    0.4 0.0367464253828938  0.0367464253828938\\
0.06    0.5 0.0574162896619585  0.0574162896619585\\
0.06    0.6 0.0826794571164541  0.0826794571164541\\
0.06    0.7 0.112535927746386   0.112535927746386\\
0.06    0.8 0.146985701551756   0.146985701551756\\
0.06    0.9 0.186028778532566   0.186028778532566\\
0.06    1   0.229665158688816   0.229665158688816\\
0.06    1.1 0.277894842012705   0.277894842012705\\
0.06    1.2 0.330717828530292   0.330717828530292\\
0.06    1.3 0.388134118173011   0.388134118173011\\
0.06    1.4 0.450143710986276   0.450143710986276\\
0.06    1.5 0.516746606973967   0.516746606973967\\
0.06    1.6 0.587942806136277   0.587942806136277\\
0.08    0.1 0.00303220449594347 0.00303220449594347\\
0.08    0.2 0.0121288179837739  0.0121288179837739\\
0.08    0.3 0.027289840453249   0.027289840453249\\
0.08    0.4 0.048515271914451   0.048515271914451\\
0.08    0.5 0.0758051123675164  0.0758051123675164\\
0.08    0.6 0.109159361812458   0.109159361812458\\
0.08    0.7 0.148578020249279   0.148578020249279\\
0.08    0.8 0.194061087677984   0.194061087677984\\
0.08    0.9 0.245608564098574   0.245608564098574\\
0.08    1   0.303220449511048   0.303220449511048\\
0.08    1.1 0.366896743907606   0.366896743907606\\
0.08    1.2 0.436637447314307   0.436637447314307\\
0.08    1.3 0.512442559662584   0.512442559662584\\
0.08    1.4 0.594312080997851   0.594312080997851\\
0.08    1.5 0.682246011323989   0.682246011323989\\
0.08    1.6 0.776244350641191   0.776244350641191\\
0.1 0.1 0.00377055252190335 0.00377055252190335\\
0.1 0.2 0.0150822100876134  0.0150822100876134\\
0.1 0.3 0.0339349726868879  0.0339349726868879\\
0.1 0.4 0.0603288403298091  0.0603288403298091\\
0.1 0.5 0.0942638130165135  0.0942638130165135\\
0.1 0.6 0.135739890747013   0.135739890747013\\
0.1 0.7 0.184757073521314   0.184757073521314\\
0.1 0.8 0.241315361339417   0.241315361339417\\
0.1 0.9 0.305414754201324   0.305414754201324\\
0.1 1   0.377055252107037   0.377055252107037\\
0.1 1.1 0.456236855048751   0.456236855048751\\
0.1 1.2 0.542959563052529   0.542959563052529\\
0.1 1.3 0.637223376049803   0.637223376049803\\
0.1 1.4 0.739028294085988   0.739028294085988\\
0.1 1.5 0.848374317164961   0.848374317164961\\
0.1 1.6 0.965261445286921   0.965261445286921\\
0.12    0.1 0.00451243489258604 0.00451243489258604\\
0.12    0.2 0.0180497395703441  0.0180497395703441\\
0.12    0.3 0.0406119140230322  0.0406119140230322\\
0.12    0.4 0.072198958260732   0.072198958260732\\
0.12    0.5 0.112810872283581   0.112810872283581\\
0.12    0.6 0.16244765609159    0.16244765609159\\
0.12    0.7 0.221109309684766   0.221109309684766\\
0.12    0.8 0.288795833063109   0.288795833063109\\
0.12    0.9 0.365507226226622   0.365507226226622\\
0.12    1   0.451243489175306   0.451243489175306\\
0.12    1.1 0.546004621901357   0.546004621901357\\
0.12    1.2 0.649790624430837   0.649790624430837\\
0.12    1.3 0.762601496695178   0.762601496695178\\
0.12    1.4 0.884437238739795   0.884437238739795\\
0.12    1.5 1.01529785056857    1.01529785056857\\
0.12    1.6 1.15518333218169    1.15518333218169\\
0.14    0.1 0.00525969968187338 0.00525969968187338\\
0.14    0.2 0.0210387987274935  0.0210387987274935\\
0.14    0.3 0.0473372971266183  0.0473372971266183\\
0.14    0.4 0.0841551948893296  0.0841551948893296\\
0.14    0.5 0.131492492015764   0.131492492015764\\
0.14    0.6 0.189349188505935   0.189349188505935\\
0.14    0.7 0.257725284359845   0.257725284359845\\
0.14    0.8 0.336620779577499   0.336620779577499\\
0.14    0.9 0.426035674158897   0.426035674158897\\
0.14    1   0.52596996810404    0.52596996810404\\
0.14    1.1 0.636423661405126   0.636423661405126\\
0.14    1.2 0.757396754088215   0.757396754088215\\
0.14    1.3 0.88888924608474    0.88888924608474\\
0.14    1.4 1.03090113744011    1.03090113744011\\
0.14    1.5 1.18343242815822    1.18343242815822\\
0.14    1.6 1.34648311823925    1.34648311823925\\
0.16    0.1 0.00601956490652337 0.00601956490652337\\
0.16    0.2 0.0240782596260935  0.0240782596260935\\
0.16    0.3 0.0541760841484682  0.0541760841484682\\
0.16    0.4 0.0963130384837294  0.0963130384837294\\
0.16    0.5 0.150489122632014   0.150489122632014\\
0.16    0.6 0.216704336593334   0.216704336593334\\
0.16    0.7 0.294958680367695   0.294958680367695\\
0.16    0.8 0.385252153955098   0.385252153955098\\
0.16    0.9 0.487584757355546   0.487584757355546\\
0.16    1   0.601956490569039   0.601956490569039\\
0.16    1.1 0.728367353587774   0.728367353587774\\
0.16    1.2 0.866817346437813   0.866817346437813\\
0.16    1.3 1.01730646905059    1.01730646905059\\
0.16    1.4 1.17983472147151    1.17983472147151\\
0.16    1.5 1.35440210370447    1.35440210370447\\
0.16    1.6 1.54100861574965    1.54100861574965\\
0.18    0.1 0.00684707188551121 0.00684707188551121\\
0.18    0.2 0.0273882875420448  0.0273882875420448\\
0.18    0.3 0.0616236469593587  0.0616236469593587\\
0.18    0.4 0.109553150147535   0.109553150147535\\
0.18    0.5 0.17117679710671    0.17117679710671\\
0.18    0.6 0.246494587836897   0.246494587836897\\
0.18    0.7 0.335506522338099   0.335506522338099\\
0.18    0.8 0.43821260061032    0.43821260061032\\
0.18    0.9 0.554612822653561   0.554612822653561\\
0.18    1   0.684707188467822   0.684707188467822\\
0.18    1.1 0.828495698045302   0.828495698045302\\
0.18    1.2 0.985978351412062   0.985978351412062\\
0.18    1.3 1.15715514849953    1.15715514849953\\
0.18    1.4 1.34202608935313    1.34202608935313\\
0.18    1.5 1.54059117397673    1.54059117397673\\
0.18    1.6 1.75285040237053    1.75285040237053\\
0.2 0.1 200 200\\
0.2 0.2 200 200\\
0.2 0.3 200 200\\
0.2 0.4 200 200\\
0.2 0.5 200 200\\
0.2 0.6 200 200\\
0.2 0.7 200 200\\
0.2 0.8 200 200\\
0.2 0.9 200 200\\
0.2 1   200 200\\
0.2 1.1 200 200\\
0.2 1.2 200 200\\
0.2 1.3 200 200\\
0.2 1.4 200 200\\
0.2 1.5 200 200\\
0.2 1.6 200 200\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

What it looks like (pgfplots ouput):

[image]

What it should look like (Matlab output):

[image]

Comment: Welcome ! What are the points at z=200 for ?

Comment: Thank you for the fast repy. I have to be honest I generated this plot with matlab2tikz. Because these values are normaly much higher, I had to limit the Z-values. Higher values threw errors in Latex.

Comment: Do you mean that you actually do not need these ponts ?

Comment: When you plot the figure in Matlab itself, do you get different colors? If yes, then could you add the Matlab output to your question? If not, then maybe the problem is on the Matlab side?

Comment: You say `point meta=\thisrow{c}` in the code, and "I think the color should be the same for the same values of Z" in the question. Why?  `point meta=\thisrow{c}` instructs pgfplots to use the entry in the `c` column for the color, not `z`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat just checked the example, datas are actually the same between `c` and `z`.

Comment: @BambOo I need this points to show that the Z values rise steeply after a certain X value

Comment: @BambOo OK, thanks, I did not check that. (But what's the purpose of having two different columns then?)

Comment: I believe the OP might want non-linear mapping into the colormap. I tried things like `point meta={ln(\thisrow{c})}` (or `z`, same values) after commenting out `point meta min` and `point meta max`, but the result isn't very convincing. I don't see any color change in the “segment” that is very steep.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I believe this is only a consequence of how `matlab2tikz` parses the coordinates

Comment: @Flo You should get what you want with `shader=faceted interp` but some lines are still problematic

Comment: @Bamboo its more about the colors than the lines. I would also be fine with something like `shader = flat` if the tiles would have the color of the mean value of their area. However even with 'shader = flat` which is the same as `shader = flat mean` the color of the tiles is not correct. I think it just uses the mean color of the shown interval of Z. Which is [0 2] not [0 - 200].

Comment: @Flo the problem is that you are trying to display large and out of the scope data converted from another software ...  it becomes kind of tricky. Do you have an analytical expression for your function or pure numerical data ?

Comment: @BambOo its pure numerical data

Comment: The color not varying with increasing `z` in the steep patch appears to be due to `zmax=2`. If you manage to “cut” your input data so that it doesn't output `z` values larger than 0.2, it should be fine.

Comment: @frougon, I tried this, but then the surface is less steep, which conflicts with the OPs requirement

Comment: @BambOo it should not be less steep if the correct interpolation is done. The x values would stop before x=0.2 of course, very shortly after x=0.18. But a different interpolation is needed for each value of y, thus some automation is highly desirable.

Comment: @frougon, I agree with you. I think there is no *clean* solution right now

Comment: Just use `\addplot3[%
surf,
shader=interp, draw=black, z buffer=sort, colormap/jet, mesh/rows=10]
table[row sep=crcr,z expr={(\thisrow{z}<1.8?\thisrow{z}:1.8)},
 point meta=\thisrow{z}] ...`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Your suggestion gives good results with `point meta=f(x)` (I commented out long ago: `point meta min`, `point meta max`, `zmin` and `zmax`).

Comment: @frougon Yes, but I thought the idea is that we should not have to install some function. To me the whole question is unclear because I do not know what the Matlab does to produce the plot. But I do believe that one needs to truncate the `z` coordinates, not only meta, like above or with `z expr={min(\thisrow{z},1.8)}`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I guess some sensor reaches its maximum output value, 200, and that's what we get... IMHO, you gave the answer the OP was expecting (but I need `point meta=f(x)`).

Comment: @frougon I do not know. To me it seems that `shader=interp` does what its name promises. Anyway, below is a community wiki anyone can play with if they want.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Schrödinger'scat's great comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/533378/pgfplots-wrong-colors-in-surface-plot#comment1348914_533378), you can use `z expr={min(\thisrow{z}, 1.8)` to truncate your `z` values. I've removed the `c` column, as it just duplicates `z` values.

Note: the output may be incorrect with some PDF viewers, so if you don't see the same as below, try another viewer. ImageMagick's `convert` tool produced the image below and Okular displays it fine, at least.

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  width=2.018in,
  height=1.698in,
  at={(0.339in,0.229in)},
  scale only axis,
  xmin=0,
  xmax=0.2,
  tick align=outside,
  xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
  xlabel={$X$},
  ymin=0,
  ymax=1.6,
  ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
  ylabel={$Y$},
  zlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
  zlabel={$Z$},
  view={-45}{45},
  axis background/.style={fill=white},
  axis x line*=bottom,
  axis y line*=left,
  axis z line*=left,
  xmajorgrids,
  ymajorgrids,
  zmajorgrids
]

\addplot3[
  surf, shader=interp, draw=black, z buffer=sort, colormap/jet, mesh/rows=10,
  ] table[row sep=crcr, z expr={min(\thisrow{z}, 1.8)}] {
%
x       y   z\\
0.02    0.1 0.000836933014342034\\
0.02    0.2 0.00334773205736814\\
0.02    0.3 0.00753239711883609\\
0.02    0.4 0.013390928208828\\
0.02    0.5 0.0209233253274806\\
0.02    0.6 0.030129588474806\\
0.02    0.7 0.0410097176508092\\
0.02    0.8 0.0535637128554926\\
0.02    0.9 0.0677915740888575\\
0.02    1   0.0836933013509049\\
0.02    1.1 0.101268894633832\\
0.02    1.2 0.1205183539637\\
0.02    1.3 0.141441679271941\\
0.02    1.4 0.16403887060397\\
0.02    1.5 0.188309927963666\\
0.02    1.6 0.214254851351224\\
0.04    0.1 0.00156389526495684\\
0.04    0.2 0.00625558105982738\\
0.04    0.3 0.0140750573743694\\
0.04    0.4 0.025022324218665\\
0.04    0.5 0.0390973815928508\\
0.04    0.6 0.0563002294969392\\
0.04    0.7 0.0766308679309348\\
0.04    0.8 0.10008929689484\\
0.04    0.9 0.126675516388657\\
0.04    1   0.156389526412386\\
0.04    1.1 0.189231326958224\\
0.04    1.2 0.225200918052232\\
0.04    1.3 0.264298299625844\\
0.04    1.4 0.306523471724472\\
0.04    1.5 0.351876434351998\\
0.04    1.6 0.400357187508615\\
0.06    0.1 0.00229665158772114\\
0.06    0.2 0.00918660635088458\\
0.06    0.3 0.0206698642792481\\
0.06    0.4 0.0367464253828938\\
0.06    0.5 0.0574162896619585\\
0.06    0.6 0.0826794571164541\\
0.06    0.7 0.112535927746386\\
0.06    0.8 0.146985701551756\\
0.06    0.9 0.186028778532566\\
0.06    1   0.229665158688816\\
0.06    1.1 0.277894842012705\\
0.06    1.2 0.330717828530292\\
0.06    1.3 0.388134118173011\\
0.06    1.4 0.450143710986276\\
0.06    1.5 0.516746606973967\\
0.06    1.6 0.587942806136277\\
0.08    0.1 0.00303220449594347\\
0.08    0.2 0.0121288179837739\\
0.08    0.3 0.027289840453249\\
0.08    0.4 0.048515271914451\\
0.08    0.5 0.0758051123675164\\
0.08    0.6 0.109159361812458\\
0.08    0.7 0.148578020249279\\
0.08    0.8 0.194061087677984\\
0.08    0.9 0.245608564098574\\
0.08    1   0.303220449511048\\
0.08    1.1 0.366896743907606\\
0.08    1.2 0.436637447314307\\
0.08    1.3 0.512442559662584\\
0.08    1.4 0.594312080997851\\
0.08    1.5 0.682246011323989\\
0.08    1.6 0.776244350641191\\
0.1 0.1 0.00377055252190335\\
0.1 0.2 0.0150822100876134\\
0.1 0.3 0.0339349726868879\\
0.1 0.4 0.0603288403298091\\
0.1 0.5 0.0942638130165135\\
0.1 0.6 0.135739890747013\\
0.1 0.7 0.184757073521314\\
0.1 0.8 0.241315361339417\\
0.1 0.9 0.305414754201324\\
0.1 1   0.377055252107037\\
0.1 1.1 0.456236855048751\\
0.1 1.2 0.542959563052529\\
0.1 1.3 0.637223376049803\\
0.1 1.4 0.739028294085988\\
0.1 1.5 0.848374317164961\\
0.1 1.6 0.965261445286921\\
0.12    0.1 0.00451243489258604\\
0.12    0.2 0.0180497395703441\\
0.12    0.3 0.0406119140230322\\
0.12    0.4 0.072198958260732\\
0.12    0.5 0.112810872283581\\
0.12    0.6 0.16244765609159\\
0.12    0.7 0.221109309684766\\
0.12    0.8 0.288795833063109\\
0.12    0.9 0.365507226226622\\
0.12    1   0.451243489175306\\
0.12    1.1 0.546004621901357\\
0.12    1.2 0.649790624430837\\
0.12    1.3 0.762601496695178\\
0.12    1.4 0.884437238739795\\
0.12    1.5 1.01529785056857\\
0.12    1.6 1.15518333218169\\
0.14    0.1 0.00525969968187338\\
0.14    0.2 0.0210387987274935\\
0.14    0.3 0.0473372971266183\\
0.14    0.4 0.0841551948893296\\
0.14    0.5 0.131492492015764\\
0.14    0.6 0.189349188505935\\
0.14    0.7 0.257725284359845\\
0.14    0.8 0.336620779577499\\
0.14    0.9 0.426035674158897\\
0.14    1   0.52596996810404\\
0.14    1.1 0.636423661405126\\
0.14    1.2 0.757396754088215\\
0.14    1.3 0.88888924608474\\
0.14    1.4 1.03090113744011\\
0.14    1.5 1.18343242815822\\
0.14    1.6 1.34648311823925\\
0.16    0.1 0.00601956490652337\\
0.16    0.2 0.0240782596260935\\
0.16    0.3 0.0541760841484682\\
0.16    0.4 0.0963130384837294\\
0.16    0.5 0.150489122632014\\
0.16    0.6 0.216704336593334\\
0.16    0.7 0.294958680367695\\
0.16    0.8 0.385252153955098\\
0.16    0.9 0.487584757355546\\
0.16    1   0.601956490569039\\
0.16    1.1 0.728367353587774\\
0.16    1.2 0.866817346437813\\
0.16    1.3 1.01730646905059\\
0.16    1.4 1.17983472147151\\
0.16    1.5 1.35440210370447\\
0.16    1.6 1.54100861574965\\
0.18    0.1 0.00684707188551121\\
0.18    0.2 0.0273882875420448\\
0.18    0.3 0.0616236469593587\\
0.18    0.4 0.109553150147535\\
0.18    0.5 0.17117679710671\\
0.18    0.6 0.246494587836897\\
0.18    0.7 0.335506522338099\\
0.18    0.8 0.43821260061032\\
0.18    0.9 0.554612822653561\\
0.18    1   0.684707188467822\\
0.18    1.1 0.828495698045302\\
0.18    1.2 0.985978351412062\\
0.18    1.3 1.15715514849953\\
0.18    1.4 1.34202608935313\\
0.18    1.5 1.54059117397673\\
0.18    1.6 1.75285040237053\\
0.2 0.1 200\\
0.2 0.2 200\\
0.2 0.3 200\\
0.2 0.4 200\\
0.2 0.5 200\\
0.2 0.6 200\\
0.2 0.7 200\\
0.2 0.8 200\\
0.2 0.9 200\\
0.2 1   200\\
0.2 1.1 200\\
0.2 1.2 200\\
0.2 1.3 200\\
0.2 1.4 200\\
0.2 1.5 200\\
0.2 1.6 200\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This answer is "Community wiki" but so far legitimately belongs to Schrödinger's cat; I'm posting it so that one can see the outcome and can improve it if necessary (Schrödinger's cat initially had a viewer problem).

Comment: Looks good! (I still do not know what this `f(x)` in `point meta=f(x)` is.)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat As I understand it, it's `y` in 2D and `z` in 3D plots...

Comment: Thanks! (I still do not see which key I set wrong... ;-) (Actually, when I compile your code I get the output of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/533391/194703). Strange.)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat  Quote from the manual for `point meta=f(x)` (*User Input Format for Point Meta*, p. 231 for `pgfplots` 1.16): “This will use the last available coordinate, in other words: it is the same as `y` for two dimensional plots and `z` for three dimensional ones.” For the rest, use `diff` or `M-x ediff-buffers`. ;-)

Comment: Yes, thanks. Actually this is not even necessary, you can also use `point meta=\thisrow{z}`, say. What is necessary is to use the right viewer....

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Arrrgh, you're right! I had figured this out meanwhile and couldn't manage to reproduce your output, so that was a viewer problem. What do I do, delete this answer and let you update yours. Or I paste my screenshot there?

Comment: There is no need to delete yours. I can remove the wiki. Maybe add a comment on the viewer subtlety.

Comment: thank you @Schrödinger'scat i think i will go with our solution. eventhough i don't think `shader=interp` does what it says. I think it should consider  z values even if they are out of range of the axis limits. Truncating the z values leads to a different steepnes of the plot. It is not much important in my case but truncating the values can not be the general solution.

Comment: As I [said](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/533378/pgfplots-wrong-colors-in-surface-plot/533397?noredirect=1#comment1348906_533378), the coloring was incorrect because you used `zmax=2`. Had you removed it, and nothing more, the coloring would have been correct, but then you would have had a scale problem. That is where the trucation is useful, in order to obtain a plot similar to yours (the “interesting” data gets all crushed if you display the whole `z` range from 0 to 200).

Comment: @Flo I don't know. I was thinking of it as follows: you have two plot points next to each other, `A` with `0.18    0.1 0.00684707188551121` and `B` with `0.2 0.1 200 200`. Now you draw a line with the color at `A` being determined by `0.00684707188551121`, which is a deep blue, and the color at `B` being red, and do a linear interpolation from blue to red. However, since `zmax=2`, as frougon reminds us, the line will be cut very close to `A`, where it is still almost perfectly blue. This is what you get, and which is why moving the point `B` down helps.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat This answer is "community wiki" too now, so feel free to play. ;-) I'm not at my computer so can't test, but maybe the OP would be happier if we used something like `inf` or `nan` instead of truncating at 1.8?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Hmm, did you look at the second plot in the question (the one from Matlab)? ;-)

Comment: @frougon You are right. I forgot that `zmax` got eliminated....